# Split text in a pandas dataframe column at a certain word

Tags: python

I want to split a text in a column at the word 'at'

This is my df:

```
Job       
Operation Manager at Barclays
Chief Operating Officer at Llyods
```

It's actually thousands of cells long but that's a snapshot.

This is what I want:

```
Job                      Location
Operating Manager        Barclays  
Chief Operating Officer  Llyods
```

This is what I tried:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.Job.str.split('at',1).tolist(), columns = ['Job','Location'])
```

This is what I get (not what I want):

```
Job               Location
Oper              ating Manager at Barclays  
Chief Oper        ating Officer at Llyods
```

so it is splitting at 'at' but in the first word it comes across the string 'at'. I want it to split at the word 'at'. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.Job.str.split(' at ',1).tolist(), columns = ['Job','Location'])
```

I get this:

```
Job                                     Location
Operating Manager at Barclays           None
Chief Operating Officer at Llyods       None
```

Comment: regex split....

Comment: can you give an example with this dataframe? I don't know how to do it. thanks

Comment: see Rakesh answer (`r"\bat\b"`). AFAIK split uses regex by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.split(r"\bat\b", expand=True)`

Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Job": ["Operation Manager at Barclays", "Chief Operating Officer at Llyods"]})
df[["Job", "Location"]] = df["Job"].str.split(r"\bat\b", expand=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                        Job   Location
0        Operation Manager    Barclays
1  Chief Operating Officer      Llyods
```

Comment: I get an error: Columns must be same length as key.   
My df is actually many more rows long, maybe that's why?

Comment: I do not think so...did you try exactly as above?

Comment: What does the r"\bat\b" do? How does it know to split at the word 'at'?

Comment: And yeah I used the same code, got an error: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: `\b` stands for boundary in Regex.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Rakesh. Yes I typed it in the same again and get the following error ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, I managed to make it work using your code. I don't know why it was so messy for me but thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 df2Init = df.Job.str.split(' at ',1, expand=True).rename({0:'Job', 1:'Location'},axis=1).to_dict()
 df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2Init)
```

Comment: I tried this but I don't get the right answer (I updated my question to include this as I forgot to add that part in).

Comment: So this gave me the same result as the Location filled with None (as the last df in my question) but the headings are 0 and 1. Heading zero containing the jobs and heading 1 containing the word None in every row. But index 1 has been renamed to 'Location' (instead of the column).

Comment: Edited the answer above and tested this time, it works :)

Comment: As for your question on the other answer, which should work (I can't yet comment there) I recommend you read the doc on [regex patterns](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Comment: So with this code It changes the column names correctly but I still get a dataframe with all text in the Job title and None written in Location. Seems like the .split(' at ') part is the problem for me. I can't seem to isolate that word using any way. Did you get the text to split at the word 'at' with spaces around it?

Comment: Weird, I got exactly the same as the desired result. Even `pd.DataFrame(df.Job.str.split(' at ',1, expand=True).rename({0:'Job', 1:'Location'},axis=1), columns=['Job', 'Location'])` works as required. I'd suggest taking a closer look at what you wrote, and if it's exactly the same as my code then something must be wrong with your starting DataFrame. Maybe try resetting the index using `.reset_index(drop=True)`, though I'm not sure how that would help. Otherwise try explictly naming the params: `.split(pat=' at ', n=1, expand=True)`, though again, not sure if it would help...

Comment: Thanks for all the help @FranciscoRZ